# HTML Styles suppressed in RDL

Tags: html, reporting-services, styles, rdl

Hi I'm in a deadlock situation. My problem is I want to apply some styles to content which is populated in RDL.

```
Ex: this is + <span style = 'color:RED'>" +  Sample + "</span>" + text.
```

and it is working fine when I enable html properties to place holder.

but here my problem is my content having some user defined tags like `<hi> this is sample text.` In this case I'm getting `this is sample text.` coz  is treating as html tag and getting suppressed.

So how can I handle both situtaions? Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You need to html encode you string before you add styles to it.

```
 &lt;hi&gt; this is + <span style = 'color:RED'>" +  Sample + "</span>" + text.
```

Comment: Actually it's exactly the opposite, you have to html decode it because a report only supports unencoded html tags.

`<span style='color:red'>Test</span` works as expected.